# Getting '1' is not a valid status after giving enum datatype in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called **production.rb**

In productions table I had created a column for status with `integer` as type then later I added `enum` datatype in the model file in-order to make it more readable. As follows:

```
class Production < ApplicationRecord    
  enum status:{
    Preproduction:1,
    Postproduction: 2,
    Completed:3
  }
end
```

The **create** and **update** actions were working fine before I added this enum datatype. Once I added that I am getting this error whenever I try creating a new record or updating for that matter:

```
ArgumentError in ProductionsController#create
'1' is not a valid status
```

**prductions_controller.rb**

```
def create
    @production = Production.new(production_params)
    #####
end


 def production_params
      params.require(:production).permit(:name, :director, :status)
 end
```

The text field in the form for entering the data:

**_form.html.erb**

```
<div class="field">
    <%= form.label :status %>
    <%= form.number_field :status, id: :production_status %>
  </div>
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: is `status` column is integer type?

Comment: @Gabbar Yes it is an integer type

Comment: ok i got it, its sending as string so you need to modify `params[:production][:status].to_i`

Comment: lets try the given solution below, let me know for further guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 def production_params
      pp = params.require(:production).permit(:name, :director)
      pp[:status] = params[:production][:status].to_i
      return pp
 end
```

after this restart your server and try again , hopefully this will work.

Answer (score 4):

Since it only accepts integer (1/2/3) or status string (Preproduction/Postproduction/Completed). Can you try to use drop-down instead:

```
form.select :status, Production.statuses.keys.to_a
```